# dpkg: error: failed to open package info file '/var/lib/dpkg/available' for reading: No such file or directory

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dpkg

I was uninstalling a software in Ubuntu(20.04), and I got these error

```
dpkg: error: failed to open package info file '/var/lib/dpkg/available' for reading: No such file or directory
E: Sub-process dpkg --set-selections returned an error code (2)
E: Couldn't record the approved state changes as dpkg selection states
```

Comment: Try `sudo dpkg --clear-avail && sudo apt update`

Comment: I suppose you have severe file system damage. Which disk drive do you use? Have you tried to run `fsck` for root filesystem from livemedia? Have you checked S.M.A.R.T information of the rootfs drive?

Comment: @nobody I encountered an another error dpkg: warning: while removing mongodb-compass, directory '/usr/share/applications' not empty so not removed

Comment: @N0rbert I am using Seagate Hard disk drive model - ST1000LM035-1RK172 (SDM3), and after checking SMART, the assessment showing. Disk is OK, 3384 bad sectors.

Comment: **3384 bad sectors** is large value. For 4K sectors it mean problematic 14 Mb. I would recommend at first to create full-backup of the drive, then run Victoria or MHDD on low-level with classic or advanced bad sectors remap on this problematic drive.

Comment: I think, I got the big problem. I will try these.

Comment: warnings about a folder is not emtpty you can ignore. but so many bad sectors surely not.